# Different STL versions?

Tags: c++, stl

I have to use library, where one of exported classes has this lines:

```
template<_Ty>
class ExportedClass
{
    typedef typename std::list<_Ty> stlContainer; 
    typedef typename stlContainer::_Tptr _Tptr; 
//many other stuff
};
```

And because std::list don't have parameter **_Tptr**, I receive many compiler errors.
It looks like there have to exist somewhere (maybe old one?) STL version with *list* that will have such parameter. But I can't find it.

Do you know that STL version? Or maye problem is somewhere else? Headers also are looking for **_Ctptr** in list that is not there too.

**RESOLVE:**
It was MSVC 2008. It looks like Microsoft STL up to 2008 was with **_Tptr** and other strange parameters.

Comment: Microsoft's probably.

Comment: `_Tptr` is not part of the official interface. Don't try to use it. (The leading underscore is a big ugly capital letters _hint_)

Comment: I just can't compile my sources with those headers because I have to include them to use their interface. And I afraid I can't change declaration of exporting class, to be able to export it correct...

Comment: @chris I tried this with MinGW32 with gcc4.8.1, and tried with Visual Studio 2013, they both don't know about "_Tptr". Maybe it is old version of some STL realization?

Comment: Too bad then. If you can't change that, you won't be able to compile your code. Time to rethink your strategy.

Comment: @juanchopanza I just can't avoid communicating with this library, it's a part of contract. I see there two ways: 1) find VS of version they used (I guess something old like VS6, and I'm sure they used VS), create wrapper that will export normal C-like functions, callable from everywhere, and call them from my project;
2) Try to use their COM interface, but usually I feel myself bloated when I have to call COM from C++...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found reference to the version of Visual Studio that used `_Tptr`.

[Visual C++ 6.0](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e29b42eb-c3c0-4f19-843b-24ecdefb956f/vc-60-code-migration-in-to-vc-vs2010-not-compile-typedef-not-work-properly?forum=vcgeneral).

I'm so very sorry.

Comment: I checked VC6, it wasn't VC. After long testing I found it was MSVC2008. Thank you for help!

Comment: @Arkady you are allowed to answer you own questions here.  That "RESOLVE" edit really should be an answer that you could mark as accepted, for other people to notice when they have your problem.  :)  (I"m glad you solved the mystery)

Answer (score 1):

This is STL implementation in Visual C++ 6.0.

Comment: I checked VC6, it wasn't VC. After long testing I found it was MSVC2008. Thank you for help!